# 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error

Tags: java

I decided that I would try to learn how to make GUIs and make one of these one of these a JAR file, so I could run it without using the Command Prompt, but every time I try to turn it into one, it gives me an error:

`'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Inside of my folder for the project, I have:

`GUI.java`, `GUI.class`, and `GUI.mf`

The file path is: `"C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Learning GUIs\TutorialGUI\FirstGUI\GUI.java"`

The manifest file has:

Main-Class: GUI

My method so far is to change the directory to Desktop/Learning GUIs/TutorialGUI/FirstGUI, and then run the command, `jar cmf GUI.mf GUI.jar GUI.class GUI.java`

However, as I noted earlier, the command prompt gives me the error message:  `'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: And is the folder that houses the `jar` utility part of your PATH?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question or not, but I just reinstalled java, and put jar.exe in the bin folder. `java -version` and `java -jar` work, but just `jar` by itself gives me the error.

Comment: I double checked to see if jar.exe is inside of the JRE bin folder, and I saw that it is. Secondly, when I looked at the PATH environment variable (I made sure that it was the system one and not the user one) I didn't see anything that looked too weird. I added another path variable that leads to the JRE (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_311`) but nothing changed when I tried to use `jar` again.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, and I am extremely thankful for your time and help!

Comment: Good to hear. I've turned these comments into an actual answer that you can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executable resolution is based on your windows PATH environment variable, so hit up the start menu, type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` and run that, then click through to "environment variables" and check whether the JDK folder is in the set of PATH locations (check the "system" one, not the user specific one).

If you install the current JDK (v17 at the time of this answer), then its folder (which is also where jar.exe lives) is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin`: don't move anything, just add that location to your system PATH, and running `jar` in a command line context should now work (but not in any cmd/ps/shell/etc. that you already had open: close and open new instances of them).